# Singleton implementation - why is a copy constructor needed?

Tags: c++, singleton, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I found this code online for the singleton design pattern:

```
class Foo
{

public:
    static Foo& getInstance()
    {
        static Foo instance;
        return instance;
    }
private:
    Foo() {};
    Foo(Foo const&);
    Foo& operator=(Foo const&);

}
```

I don't understand why the constructor `Foo(Foo const&);` and the `Foo& operator=(Foo const&);` are both needed. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: The copy constructor is private which means that you can't call it. Not being able to make a copy is exactly what you want with a singleton, by not being able to call it we are essentially preventing copying.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why are people downvoting my question? I think what I'm asking is pretty clear and I couldn't find another question on SO asking the same thing..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wouldn't you want the following code to fail?

```
int main() {
    // Utilizes the copy constructor
    Foo x = Foo::getInstance();
    Foo y = Foo::getInstance();

    // Utilizes the operator=
    x = Foo::getInstance();
}
```

Note that we've created 3 new instances of `Foo` by the end of that code.

Answer (score 4):

The copy constructor and assignment operator are declared in private section and not defined, which means that in fact no one can use them, so no copies of `Foo` can be created.

Note that in C++11 this can be achieved in more straightforward way:

```
// this can be even in public section
Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = delete;
```

Answer (score 4):

### To prevent accidentally assigning the singleton.

With private copy constructor the following code will NOT compile:

```
Foo foo = Foo::getInstance(); // error: ‘Foo::Foo(const Foo&)’ is private
```

With private no argument constructor the following code will NOT compile:

```
Foo foo2; // error: ‘Foo::Foo()’ is private
```

You use this gymnastics to ensure that people who use your singleton will use it the way it was intended, through the **getInstance()** static function.

Comment: I guess, if we declare private destructor  then no need of private copy-constructor. the code will not compile.

Comment: As I tested it can be able to compiled actually https://godbolt.org/z/TaMvroEY8 . But when you disable the copy constructor program will not be compiled for this case.