# How to call the function of singleton pattern?

Tags: c++, singleton

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26266280/462608

That link shows the following ways of calling are not allowed:

```
int main() {
    // Utilizes the copy constructor
    Foo x = Foo::getInstance();
    Foo y = Foo::getInstance();

    // Utilizes the operator=
    x = Foo::getInstance();
}
```

Then what is the way to call the function `getInstance` w.r.t Singleton pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the examples are showing is that it is an error to copy the singleton instance refered to by the return from `Foo::getInstance()`.

You can avoid that either by capturing the returned reference

```
Foo& x = Foo::getInstance();
```

or by directly calling the method you are interested in

```
Foo::getInstance().some_method();
```

Comment: Oh, that means that the object has been already created inside the class itself, now our job is to use it to call relevant functions. Thank you.